# how to define grayscale out of pure white or black

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Suppose I have defined `$color-white: #ffffff` and/or `$color-black: #000000` in `variables.sass`.

How can I define different shades of grey scale using either SASS or Compass helpers?

Answer (score 1):

Use color functions: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#other_color_functions

```
color: darken($color-white, 25%);
```

or

```
color: lighten($color-black, 25%);
```

toy with the numeric value until your heart is content.